# Check if column value is zero MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view which has a complicated CASE statement to determine the value of one of the columns.

```
SELECT a.itemcode, count(*) total, b.foo
    CASE 
    WHEN foo IN ('aab', 'aac')
    THEN 1
    WHEN foo IN ('qqq', 'fff')
    THEN 2
    WHEN foo IN ('foo', 'bar')
    THEN 10 % count(*)
    ELSE 9 % count(*)
    END AS other_total

FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.itemcode = b.itemcode
GROUP BY itemcode, foo
```

I want to add a check for the value of the column other_total. If it is `0`, I want to set the value to `1`.

Obviously I could surround the whole thing in a `CASE` statement...

```
CASE ( CASE 
    WHEN foo IN ('aab', 'aac')
    THEN 1
    WHEN foo IN ('qqq', 'fff')
    THEN 2
    WHEN foo IN ('foo', 'bar')
    THEN 10 % count(*)
    ELSE 9 % count(*)
    END )
WHEN 0 THEN 1
ELSE  CASE 
    WHEN foo IN ('aab', 'aac')
    THEN 1
    WHEN foo IN ('qqq', 'fff')
    THEN 2
    WHEN foo IN ('foo', 'bar')
    THEN 10 % count(*)
    ELSE 9 % count(*)
    END
END AS other_total
```

But this is just a bit messy and seems like there should be an easier way.

Is there another function, similar to `ISNULL()`, that would allow me to change the value of the column if it equals zero?

ANSWER

Thanks to gofr1's answer I was able to work this one out. I used the NULLIF function to return NULL if the case statement was equal to 0, then surrounded with an ISNULL function to set the value to 1 if the NULLIF function returned NULL.

```
SELECT a.itemcode, count(*) total, b.foo,
    ISNULL (
        NULLIF (
            CASE 
            WHEN foo IN ('aab', 'aac')
            THEN 1
            WHEN foo IN ('qqq', 'fff')
            THEN 2
            WHEN foo IN ('foo', 'bar')
            THEN 10 % count(*)
            ELSE 9 % count(*)
            END 
        ), 0)
    ), 1) other_total

FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.itemcode = b.itemcode
GROUP BY itemcode, foo
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

> Returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.

```
CASE WHEN 
NULLIF(
    CASE WHEN foo IN ('aab', 'aac') THEN 1
        WHEN foo IN ('qqq', 'fff') THEN 2
        WHEN foo IN ('foo', 'bar') THEN 10 % count(*)
        ELSE 9 % count(*)
        END
    ,0) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
 AS other_total
```

If value `= 0` then it becomes `NULL` else the value is in output. Then we use `CASE WHEN value IS NULL then 0 else 1`.

Comment: Thanks - I changed the outer CASE statement to ISNULL which sorted it

Comment: My pleasure to help! ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT NullIf(<your_code>, 0) AS zero_to_null
     , Coalesce(NullIf(<your_code>, 0), 1) AS zero_to_null_to_one
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN other_total = 0 THEN 1 ELSE other_total END AS new_total
FROM   (
        <your_code>
       ) AS a_subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

use DERIVED QUERY or CTE

-- Derived query

```
SELECT itemcode, total, foo, case when other_total = 0 then 1 else other_total end as other_total
FROM
(
  SELECT a.itemcode, count(*) total, b.foo
      CASE 
      WHEN foo IN ('aab', 'aac')
      THEN 1
      WHEN foo IN ('qqq', 'fff')
      THEN 2
      WHEN foo IN ('foo', 'bar')
      THEN 10 % count(*)
      ELSE 9 % count(*)
      END AS other_total

  FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.itemcode = b.itemcode
  GROUP BY itemcode, foo
) d
```

OR

you can just use CASE on the last 2 expression of the CASE WHEN... since that is the only 2 places that will gives you 0.

```
  WHEN foo IN ('foo', 'bar')
  THEN CASE WHEN 10 % count(*) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 10 % count(*) END
  ELSE CASE WHEN  9 % count(*) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE  9 % count(*) END
  END AS other_total
```